# Aggregate in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I did look at a lot of code example but I never found out something I want. Actually I could do a loop but I would really prefer to use the mongo engine to get the result as I want it. It even more crazy that I begin to spend lot of time on it and looks so basic ...

I'm running with nodeJS with Express and MongoDB.

Basically I have a collection with some information like :

```
{
  "aqi": 149,
  "area": "AL",
  "position_name": "montgomery",
  "station_code": "1793A",
},
{
  "aqi": 162,
  "area": "AL",
  "position_name": "huntsville",
  "station_code": "1790A",
},
{
  "aqi": 73,
  "area": "TX",
  "position_name": "dallas",
  "station_code": "1792A",
}
```

I would like to get a result dataset like

```
{
  "_id": "AL",
  "positions": [
    {
      "position_name": "montgomery",
      "station_code": "1793A"
    },
    {
      "position_name": "huntsville"
      "station_code": "1790A"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id": "TX",
  "positions": [
    {
      "position_name": "dallas",
      "station_code": "1793A"
    }
  ]
}
```

So far I really think I did check all over stackoverflow and try several solutions, meanwhile if I'm wrong and the questions with similar problem already exist, please kindly let me know and I apologize in advance.

My current code :

```
db.collection('cities', function(err, collection) {
  collection.aggregate([{$group : {_id : "$area"}}], function(err, items) {
    res.send(items);
  });
});
```

I was thinking to mix match (area) and group but no success until now.

Thank you for your help.

**Edit :**

I did forget the group operator to do this. Here the new code :

```
db.collection('cities', function(err, collection) {    
  collection.aggregate([{$group : {_id: "$area", positions: {$push : "$position_name"}}}], function(err, items) {
    res.send(items);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you first need to come to terms with this being an [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) and the important thing to get thinking about is just like piping results from one shell command to another, this is what you are doing in aggregation.

So you got started but you need more steps. Without spoon feeding I'll just say look at the [**$push**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) operator and it should point you in the right direction.

Also try to spend some time going through the operators and tutorial examples given.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-zip-code-data-set/

Comment: It was the push in fact ... I did only check about Pipeline operator and forgot the group operators ... Thanks ;)

I edited my question with the reply.